# Get the ID of clicked radio button in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to get the id of the radio button that is checked in android, this is my XML code,

```
                <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioAuction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:onClick="showAuctionOptions"
                android:textColor="#3DCC00"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioBin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="Buy it now" />
```

so once it has been clicked it runs showAuctionOptions, this is my java code,

```
        public void showAuctionOptions(View v){


    if(findViewById(R.id.v=="RadioAuction")){
    //Display start price
    LinearLayout ShowPrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutStartPrice);
    ShowPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Display reserve price
    LinearLayout ShowReservePrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutReservePrice);
    ShowReservePrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work, does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (v == findViewById(R.id.RadioAuction)){
LinearLayout ShowPrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutStartPrice);
    ShowPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Display reserve price
    LinearLayout ShowReservePrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutReservePrice);
    ShowReservePrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

If this doesn't cut it either, make sure you've set the on click listeners for those radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Probably faster would be:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.RadioAuction){
  LinearLayout ShowPrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutStartPrice);
  ShowPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  //Display reserve price
  LinearLayout ShowReservePrice = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutReservePrice);
  ShowReservePrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

And that way you can use the R values in a switch statement, if you have a long radio list:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.RadioAuction:
    // Do stuff
   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, although this doesn't seem to work. I get 'getId cannot be resolved or is not a field' error

Comment: Sorry... it's a function... so `v.getId();`